# How to get String between last two underscore

Tags: java, regex

I have a string `"abcde-abc-db-tada_x12.12_999ZZZ_121121.333"`

The result I want should be `999ZZZ`

I have tried using:

```
private static String getValue(String myString) {
    
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(\\d+)_1");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));  // Should print 999ZZZ
    }
    else {
         System.out.println("not found"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cardinal System: updated the question Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to continue with a regex based approach, then use the following pattern:

```
.*_([^_]+)_.*
```

This will greedily consume up to and including the second to last underscrore.  Then it will consume and capture `9999ZZZ`.

Code sample:

```
String name = "abcde-abc-db-tada_x12.12_999ZZZ_121121.333";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*_([^_]+)_.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
if (m.matches()) {

    System.out.println(m.group(1));  // Should print 999ZZZ

} else {
     System.out.println("not found"); 
}
```

### Demo

Answer (score 6):

Using String.split?

```
String given = "abcde-abc-db-tada_x12.12_999ZZZ_121121.333";
String [] splitted = given.split("_");
String result = splitted[splitted.length-2];
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `split` you can use `substring` as well:

```
String s = "abcde-abc-db-tada_x12.12_999ZZZ_121121.333";
        String ss = (s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("_"))).substring((s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("_"))).lastIndexOf("_")+1);
        System.out.println(ss);
```

OR,

```
String s = "abcde-abc-db-tada_x12.12_999ZZZ_121121.333";
        String arr[] = s.split("_");
        System.out.println(arr[arr.length-2]);
```

Comment: Regex is there to give a more readable solution than the first one, the second is still using a regex (simpler version but still), so I would keep the capture group, mostly because this is safer, or you need to add some length check first.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I was just trying to give alternate solution.

Comment: And those are correct, I used both depending on the need. But on the first one, I would not do that on one line to keep it readable and safety need to be added for the second one (or at least a warning sign ;) )

Answer (score 0):

The get text between the last two underscore characters, you first need to find the index of the last two underscore characters, which is very easy using `lastIndexOf`:

```
String s = "abcde-abc-db-tada_x12.12_999ZZZ_121121.333";
String r = null;
int idx1 = s.lastIndexOf('_');
if (idx1 != -1) {
    int idx2 = s.lastIndexOf('_', idx1 - 1);
    if (idx2 != -1)
        r = s.substring(idx2 + 1, idx1);
}
System.out.println(r); // prints: 999ZZZ
```

This is faster than any solution using regex, including use of `split`.

Answer (score -1):

As I misunderstood the logic from the code in question a bit with the first read and in the meantime there appeared some great answers with the use of regular expressions, this is my try with the use of some methods contained in String class (it introduces some variables just to make it more clear to read, it could be written in the shorter way of course) :

```
String s = "abcde-abc-db-ta__dax12.12_999ZZZ_121121.333";
int indexOfLastUnderscore = s.lastIndexOf("_");
int indexOfOneBeforeLastUnderscore = s.lastIndexOf("_", indexOfLastUnderscore - 1);
if(indexOfLastUnderscore != -1 && indexOfOneBeforeLastUnderscore != -1) {
    String sub = s.substring(indexOfOneBeforeLastUnderscore + 1, indexOfLastUnderscore);
    System.out.println(sub);
}
```